# Chilkat: sftp support for key exchange ciphers

Tags: sftp, sha256, chilkat, curve-25519

I am developing a .NET Core application and need sFTP support including KexAlgorithm curve25519-sha256 cipher.  Does the .NET product provide support for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Chilkat supports it...…...